# Как выровнять изображение на уровне поля для ввода?

Tags: html

http://jsfiddle.net/1zk6ahfu/2/embedded/result/

Comment: Пожалуйста, оформите пример на http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Ну а как сделать, чтобы было всем доступно, чтоб вы видели?

Comment: @Алексей31 оформите на выше указанном сайте и ссылку добавите в вопрос(ссылка Править - под вашим вопросом)

Comment: @Алексей31, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте для вашего `input` и `img` следующие стили:

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/1zk6ahfu/19/

Решение, конечно, так себе, но можете попробовать сделать стиль с ключом relative и задать позицию элемента ввода относительно изображения как родителя.

```
 <input name="pr" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: -5px;" type="text" size="15"
                         maxlength="5">
```